# Flutter: ImagePicker convert bmp(bitmap) image to jpg image

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am using [image_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker) to pick images in my project, but when I pick an image with a `.bmp` extension but `image_picker` automatically converts it with a `.jpg` file.

Code:

```
 final image = await picker
      .getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery)
      .catchError((error) {
    return null;
  });
```

Does anyone have any idea how I can fix it?

Answer (score 1):

If you using plugin on iOS, its only supports `.png` and `.jpg` (you can find the similar [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/17947) on plugin's issue tracker on GitHub). If you using it on Android, visit to [this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/47719) issue for track actual state of the problem.